# is DOMCORE v3 still compatible with PHP 5?

Tags: php

I use DOMCORE v2 on PHP5 server and I saw that DOMCORE v3 is compatible with PHP7. Is it still compatible with PHP 5 ? is it safe to upgrade ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the domcore is fully compatible backwards with PHP 5.2- (no traits), PHP 5.3+ (traits) and PHP7 (use of \Error throwable instead of \Exeption)

- Phil